# Why transpose the weight vector in Perceptron Convergence Theorem

Tags: computer-science, machine-learning

We have a training set D with a bunch of input vectors x and desired output of y.

We are aiming to make a perceptron that can separate the input vectors x in accordance with their desired output y. The end goal of a perceptron algorithm is to have the weight vector w, input vector x and output vector y that satisfies the following:

$$
y ⋅ (w^{T}\cdot x) > 0
$$
For every point in our dataset that needs to be satisfied until we can finish training.
Now the perceptron convergence theorem proves that this can be achieved in a finite amount of loops.
What I do not understand however and what I would appreciate some help with is understanding as to why we transpose the weight vector w. Why does it need to be:
$$w^T$$
Why can't the normal weight vector w just be used?

I appreciate all help, thank you. Also I hope this is the correct place to post this question.

Comment: $w^Tx$ is the dot product of the two vectors.

Comment: Yes, but isn't $$w \cdot x$$ also the dot product of the two vectors? Why does it have to be $$w^{T}x$$

Comment: The dots in that expression don’t appear to represent a dot product, but rather matrix multiplication. Compare to the notation in other parts of the material that you’re using.